# Error in makefile while build process of binutils

Tags: makefile, operating-system, cross-compiling, binutils

I am following [this](https://users-cs.au.dk/sortie/dopsys/osdev/) tutorial to develop a hello world operating system. 
The config part shown below gets done successfully

```
# Delete the build directory if it already exists.
rm -rfv binutils-build
mkdir binutils-build
cd binutils-build

../binutils-2.23.1/configure --prefix=$HOME/opt/cross --target=i586-elf \
                         --disable-nls
```

But when I execute make `nice make -j4` I get the following errors:

```
config.status: creating po/Makefile.in
config.status: executing depfiles commands
config.status: executing libtool commands
config.status: executing default-1 commands
config.status: executing bfd_stdint.h commands
config.status: executing default commands
make[3]: Nothing to be done for 'info'.
make[3]: Leaving directory '/home/souban/OS/binutils-build/bfd/po'
make[3]: Entering directory '/home/souban/OS/binutils-build/bfd'
make[3]: Nothing to be done for 'info-am'.
make[3]: Leaving directory '/home/souban/OS/binutils-build/bfd'
Makefile:1617: recipe for target 'info-recursive' failed
make[2]: *** [info-recursive] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/souban/OS/binutils-build/bfd'
Makefile:2505: recipe for target 'all-bfd' failed
make[1]: *** [all-bfd] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/souban/OS/binutils-build'
Makefile:837: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The actual error message is not in the part you quoted, but the build process probably cannot find the `makeinfo` program, which is part of the `texinfo` package in most distributions.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone else coming across this error, you can get around it by running the `configure` command with `MAKEINFO=missing` in front of it... i.e.

```
MAKEINFO=missing ../binutils-2.23.1/configure --prefix=$HOME/opt/cross --target=i586-elf --disable-nls
```

And likewise with `make`:

```
MAKEINFO=missing make -j8
```